# How to show data from 3 tables in crystal report using c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2010

I need to show data on crystal report, my tables are as below

```
ClientServiceMaster (ServiceNo, ComplainDate, AttainDate, Counter)

ServiceDetail(ServiceNo, Problem, Reason, Action)

ReplacementDetail (ServiceNo, ItemNo, Qty)
```

Here `ClientServiceMaster` Data is only once, so I have kept that in Page Header
But there would be more then one records for `ServiceDetail` as well as `ReplacementDetail`, I want to show each rows of these both tables.

Kindly Help me in which section I need to add these tables and how to write code

Khilen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **sub reports**.
You can use separate queries with datasets with the relevant data.

Here are some samples.. Hope you'll find something...

http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-subreports.htm
http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/43691-How-create-sub-reports-crystal-report.aspx

Comment: For More SubReports we can add condition as shown below 

foreach (ReportObject repOp in Rd.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects)
{
      if (repOp.Kind == ReportObjectKind.SubreportObject)
      {
                        string SubRepName = ((SubreportObject)repOp).SubreportName;

                        if (SubRepName.Equals("RD"))
                        {
                            ReportDocument subRepDoc2 = Rd.Subreports[SubRepName];
                            subRepDoc2.SetDataSource(dt2);
                        }
                    }
                }